# ElasticSearch: подсчет уникальных пар без скриптов

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

Я хочу переписать этот sql-запрос (посчитать количество пользователей с уникальными данными):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age, Id, COUNT(*)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, Age, Id
```

на язык ElasticSearch, поля с соответствующими названиями там есть.
Проблема в том, что аггрегатор `cardinality` умеет работать только с одним `term'ом` или со скриптами, но последние на моём сервере запрещены. Как можно обойтись без них?

Comment: Если вы выбираете уникальные строки из таблицы, а потом группируете по ним же, то count всегда даст 1. Т.е. ваш запрос эквивалентен следующему:

SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Age, Id, 1 FROM TableName

Comment: Да, спасибо, поправила запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На такой запрос SQL ты получишь таблицу вида:

```
| FirstName | LastName | Age |  Id  | Count |
| Ivan      | Ivanov   | 15  |  134 | 1     |
| Ivan      | Petrov   | 17  |  132 | 2     |
```

Тот же результат на elasticseach можно получить вложенной агрегацией по [Terms Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)

Пример на PHP клиенте:

```
$res = $client->search(
  [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
      'query' => [
        'filtered' => [
          'query' => [ 'match_all' => [] ],
          'filter' => []
        ]
      ],
      'aggregations' => [
        'FirstName' => [
          'terms' => [
            'field' => 'FirstName',
            'size' => 0,
          ],
          'aggregations' => [
            'LastName' => [
              'terms' => [
                'field' => 'LastName',
                'size' => 0,
              ],
              'aggregations' => [
                'Age' => [
                  'terms' => [
                    'field' => 'Age',
                    'size' => 0,
                  ],
                  'aggregations' => [
                    'Id' => [
                      'terms' => [
                        'field' => 'Id',
                        'size' => 0,
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
);
```

На ветвях 'Id' вы получите кол-во документов

Но если задача стоит исключить дубликаты, то я бы обратил внимание на [статью](https://qbox.io/blog/minimizing-document-duplication-in-elasticsearch).

Answer (score 0):

вот поможет - [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)
Краткий пример:
Records

```
PUT items/1
{ "language" : 10 }

PUT items/2
{ "language" : 11 }

PUT items/3
{ "language" : 10 }
```

Query

```
GET items/_search
{ ... }

# => Expected Response
[10, 11]

{
"size": 0,
"aggs" : {
    "langs" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "language" }
    }
}}
```

Поиск вернется что-то вроде:

```
{
"took" : 16,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
  "total" : 2,
  "successful" : 2,
  "failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
"total" : 1000000,
"max_score" : 0.0,
"hits" : [ ]
},
"aggregations" : {
  "langs" : {
    "buckets" : [ {
      "key" : "10",
      "doc_count" : 244812
    }, {
      "key" : "11",
      "doc_count" : 136794

    }, {
      "key" : "12",
      "doc_count" : 32312
       } ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: нету где проверить возможно ошибся где.